# How to read emails with utf8 characters using imaplib

Tags: python, email, imap

I am trying to read emails using imaplib, but for some reason the utf8 characters aren't showing correctly. For example, the email: `soporte técnico` result: `soporte t=C3=A9cnico`

```py
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email@gmail.com', 'pass')
mail.select('inbox')
res, mailList = mail.search(None, "FROM", "noreply@test.com")
for x in reversed(mailList[0].split()):
    typ, dataMail = mail.fetch(str(int(x)), '(RFC822)')
    print(dataMail[0][1].decode("utf8"))
```

What can I do in order to read emails with utf8 characters correctly? Thanks

Comment: It may not be a UTF-8 encoded message.  Check the header of the email for a content-encoding.

Comment: You have a value with either [Q encoding](https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1522/6.htm) or actual [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Example) (Q encoding is used in message headers, quoted-printable in the message body, check the Content-Transfer-Encoding header) - there helper functions that deal with these encodings, look for them.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you for your reply. I have tried using the module `quopri` to decode the email but now it is returning me this: `M\xc3\xa1s informaci\xc3\xb3n en` from `Más información en` and if I try to decode to utf8 it shows this error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 1095: invalid continuation byte

Comment: The topic of the duplicate _question_ is quite different, but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working like this:

```py
import imaplib
import email
import email.policy

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email@gmail.com', 'pass')
mail.select('inbox')
res, mailList = mail.search(None, "FROM", "noreply@test.com")
for x in reversed(mailList[0].split()):
    typ, dataMail = mail.fetch(str(int(x)), '(RFC822)')
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(dataMail[0][1], policy=email.policy.default)
    
    #get the body of the email
    body = ""
    for part in msg.walk():
        charset = part.get_content_charset()
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
            partStr = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            body += partStr.decode(charset)

    print(body)
```

Comment: `message_from_string` is wrong here; just don't try to decode the `bytes` at all - pass them to `message_from_bytes` instead.

Comment: Also, you want to use the modern `email` API which (cumbersomely) requires an `email.policy` argument.